# Creating An empty gameobject, storing the data of an existing gameobject in the new gameobject and then destroying the existing gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, gameobject

I want to store the existing data of a game object in a new game object (Without instantiating it until I want too) and then delete the existing game object thus giving me an exact clone (which is not instantiated in the scene)

So I stored the copy of the game object in a list as I want multiple of them that I can instantiate at any time. If I don't Destroy(ExisitngGameObject), a copy will be made however when I destroy existing game object the supposedly copied game object will be missing object in the List

```
`//#1
GameObject CloneObj;
CloneObj = ExistingObj;
CloneList.Add(CloneObj)
Destory(ExisitingObj);`

//2 
GameObject CloneObj = new gameobject();
CloneObj = ExistingObj;
CloneList.Add(CloneObj)
Destory(ExisitingObj);`

//#3
CloneObj = Instantiate(ExisitingObj);
CloneObj = ExistingObj;
CloneList.Add(CloneObj)
Destory(ExisitingObj);`

//#4
GameObject CloneObj= new GameObject();
CloneObj.name = ExisitingObj.name;
CloneObj.transform.position =ExisitingObj.transform.position;
CloneObj.transform.rotation = ExisitingObj.transform.rotation;
CloneObj.transform.localScale = ExisitingObj.transform.localScale;
CloneObj = ExistingObj;
CloneList.Add(CloneObj)
Destory(ExisitingObj);
`
```

Results:

1 - Missing Object in list when destroyed existing object

2 - creates an empty game object in scene

3 - creates an inactive game object clone in the scene which I do not want

4 - creates a clone which is in the scene with only transform values which I do not want.

I would only like to store a copy kof the existing game object and destroy it and instantiate the stored copy from the list in the future e.g press a button or something happens.

Answer (score 1):

take your attempt 3 and skip line 2:

```
CloneObj = Instantiate(ExisitingObj);
//CloneObj = ExistingObj; //remove this line
CloneList.Add(CloneObj)
Destory(ExisitingObj);
```

First you make your instance, but then you replace a reference to your new instance with a reference to the original object, you add it to the list and destroy it. If I understand correctly you want to keep the reference to the new object but destroy the old one, so don't loose a reference to the new one

Comment: Check out a codebook explaining the concept reference variables.. The = operator copies the address of your original object to the new object, it does not copy the data contents of the new object. There are ways to do this, but to be honest, I very rarely need to do that. So maybe you need to start with the question why you want to have a clone of the object?